# Should I include phonegap.js in a Phonegap 3 app?

Tags: ios, xcode, html, cordova

I could not find in the PhoneGap documentation an answer. When creating a new PhoneGap 3.0 for iOS, do I need to include "phonegap.js" in my index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to include phonegap.js in your pages if you are using some of the core API calls like `device.ready`. If you aren't, you don't need to include it.

Comment: However, in the default "helloworld" generated, the file is not included and the device.ready seems to be fired... I am a bit lost of what to do.

Comment: See the full example of the phonegap device API (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.name). It shows using it. Anyways, there is no harm in including it. It will add an extremely small amount to your overall application size and will not have any effect on performance.

Comment: My mistake. It is included in the default "helloworld".